# Using CocoaPods for the "Charts" framework. Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, charts, cocoapods, ios-charts

I am a newbie when it comes to CocoaPods so please bear with me!
I am looking at the tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift) however this is using the dependency "pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'". I have looked online for over a hour now and I can't find what to use for the Charts framework (https://cocoapods.org/?q=charts).

So Far i have done the following steps:

1.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and got the following output:

[image]

2.

```
pod setup --verbose
```

and got the following output:

[image]

3.

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

and got the following result :

[image]

4.

Uncommented "use_frameworks!" and uncommented "platform :ios, '6.0'" and changed it to "platform :ios, '9.0'"

Now i am stuck as i don't know what dependancies i need to use for the charts framework. Apologies if this is a very simple answer!

Thanks in advanced for your help :)

EDIT: After installing the pod files i dragged the 'Charts.xcodeproj file into my project.

When i try and embed binaries i have various options:

[image]

When i add them and build i get the following errors:

[image]

Comment: Add pod 'Charts' to your Podfile. "Charts" is the name of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey First you have to decide which chart library You want to use.
Something like this https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

for above chart library you have to use

```
pod 'Charts'
```

in your pod file inside the project .

Now your pod file will be something like this

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Charts'
```

Now open the terminal and go to your project directory and enter the command

```
pod install
```

and you are good to go.
Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks @imagngames! Do i remove all the other bits from the podfile and just have the above?

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: after the pod install please see here how to use the library here https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

Comment: Thanks! I have followed the steps on the link provided however i have encountered some errors. I have posted them on a edit above. Can you help with those too? Thanks!

Comment: After installing the pod files i dragged the 'Charts.xcodeproj file into my project. why are you dragging Charts.xcodeproj ?  After pod install just open your project clicking on white (not blue) Charts.xcodeproj icon .

Comment: on github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts under usage it says to do so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107718/discussion-between-imagngames-and-jess-murray).

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are instructions on what CocoaPod name to use for installation on the GitHub or source code hosting page of the library.

After a pod install command under your correct project directory, you need to exit out of your .xcodeproject and open up the workspace file. This is what you do from now on after a project has a cocoapod dependency. The workspace now contains both your project, and the pods project as a package manager. The pod(s) you installed are there, and must be accessed by importing the name of the CocoaPod (can be seen in folder drop down view in the Pods project).

You do not need to drag anymore files in your own project or embed like before. Make sure to delete those.

If you're still having trouble, can you edit what your current podfile looks like?